# Echo statements in Yocto recipe not printing to terminal

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am trying to debug my `do_compile_append` function in a Yocto recipe, by printing messages:

```sh
do_compile_append() {
    for i in 1 2 3 4 5
    do
        echo "My yocto Looping ... number $i"
    done
}
```

In this example, I have added a loop to echo some messages during the build. However, when I run `bitbake` to build it, I don't see these messages output to my terminal.

Where is the output logged?

Comment: You could do a find at 'log.do_compile*'.  BTW, you could also check the output of 'bitbake -e RECIPE'.

Answer (score 7):

Bitbake provides logging functions for use in Shell Script code.

You can have a look to the `poky/plain/meta/classes/logging.bbclass` which is inherited by default by many recipes.

Functions are : `bbplain`, `bbnote`, `bbwarn`, `bberror`, `bbfatal`, `bbdebug`

So thus, you could use `bbdebug "My yocto Looping ... number $i"` to print outputs in your terminal.

Answer (score 7):

Here's what to do to see your own debug:

#### 1

Add the following directive to your recipe file

```
inherit logging
```

#### 2

In any function, use the following to print debug (under the yellow warning color). You can refer to environment variables defined in the shell with `${VARIABLE-ID}`.

```
do_compile_append(){
    bbwarn "Hello, this is a debug message from ${USER}"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

By default all the logs of executed tasks are stored in `${WORKDIR}/temp/log.do_xxx`. For your recipe you can check your debug outputs in `${WORKDIR}/temp/log.do_compile`.

To see outputs on terminal, you should use special functions from below bbclass `poky/plain/meta/classes/logging.bbclass` like this `bbdebug "My yocto Looping ... number $i"`

Answer (score 3):

In case bitbake runs Python you will need to write the logging this way:

```
inherit logging

...

do_fetch_append(){
    bb.warn("Hello")
}
```

It will show in the logs as follow:

```
WARNING: xxxx-x.xx-xx do_fetch: Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

use `bbnote "...."` in recipe or `bb.note("...")` in python and run `bitbake -v`